# how pass array to constructor java?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

How pass array to Constructor with one parameter integer 
I want to save all the value of array in a1

when use this code :

```
//Constructor,,int a1

welcome(int…a)

    {
        for(int b:a)
        {
             a1=b;
        }

    }
```

OUTPUT display like this
if write 1 & 2 as value of array 
the output will be :

2

2

that is mean print just last value of array

BUT want output like this :

1

2

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int size;

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    size=input.nextInt();
    int []f= new int[size];

   jk e=new jk();

   e.fill(f);
}
```

---

```
public class jk {

private welcome a;
private int b;

public void fill(int f[])  
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0;i<f.length;i++)
    {
       b=input.nextInt();
       a=new welcome(b);
    }


    for (int j=0;j<f.length;j++)
    {
       a.print();
    }
}


}
```

---

```
public class welcome {

private  int  a1;

welcome(int...a)
{
    for(int b:a)
    {
         a1=b;

    }

}

public void print()
{
    System.out.println(a1);
}
}
```

Comment: This code does not output anything. Please include the code that actually outputs something.

Comment: What is `a1`? You never initialize it as an `int` or an `int[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop:

```
for(int b:a)
{
     a1=b;
}
```

*just* repeatedly assigns the value of `b` to `a1` - so yes, when the loop has finished, `a1` will have the value of the last value in `a`. If you want to print out the values, you need to put the output in the loop:

```
for (int b : a) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

You haven't shown where your *current* output is - but if you're just repeatedly printing `a1` then it will keep printing the same value.

EDIT: Now that we've seen your code, you just need to change `a1` to be an array:

```
public class Welcome { // Names changed to be more conventional
    private final int[] values;

    public Welcome(int... values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void printValues() {
        for (int value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `fill` method to need to populate the array:

```
public void fill(int[] f) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
       f[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    a = new Welcome(f);
    a.printValues();
}
```

Previously you were creating one instance of your class on each iteration of the loop. You should look very carefully over your original code - ideally working through it in a debugger. It's important to understand why the original code didn't work just as much as how to fix it.

Comment: don't want print values in Constructor because want use method for print in another class. Thank you Jon

Comment: @user2966789: Then you'll need to store the array (or a copy of it, or maybe a list built from it) via an instance variable. It really doesn't help that you've given us so little information in your question. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: ok,
NOW edit my question & add the code =)

Comment: Yes, I knew where the error in the code now
Thank you very much Jon.